# Add comma and zero value after decimal to a string of Number after thousand in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hi i'm getting price from backend API in a string type, i'm trying to place comma after thousand and `.00` after the string. I f string has some value after decimal then it should display that value like, `23,000.55` else if after decimal there is nothing then want to show value like this `23,000.00` . How i can make format like this? I have tried NumberFormatter but when i run app, it only show comma after thousand but not double zero after decimal. This is my code,

```
    let balanceValue = Double(price ?? "0.0")
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    let formattedNumber = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:balanceValue ?? 0.0))
```

When i print this value, it shows value like this, `23,000`. I want it to show like this, `23,000.00`

Comment: Read the documentation about the `NumberFormatter`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter.
There are properties that can help you achieve what you are looking for.
Check out the section `Configuring Integer and Fraction Digits`

Comment: Add `numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2`. You may also want to add `numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2`

Comment: Suppose if price have value after decimal will it show actual value or zeros. @Daniel

Comment: @Hamzayes, if you set `minimumFractionDigits = 2` it will always show at least 2 digits of the fraction. Which means that `1` would be formatted as `1.00`, `1.2` as `1.20`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format the amount of digits shown by using [minimumFractionDigits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumberformatter/1410459-minimumfractiondigits?language=objc) and [maximumFractionDigits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumberformatter/1415364-maximumfractiondigits?language=objc).

As the name suggests, it set's the minimal and maximal amount of digits. In your case, the code would be:

```
let balanceValue = Double(price ?? "0.0")
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
let formattedNumber = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:balanceValue ?? 0.0))
```

`print(formattedNumber)` would now output `23,000.00`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it get fixed by adding numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2 . @Daniel

Comment: There is no need to initialize a new `NSNumber` object. you can use Formatter's method `string(for: Any)` and pass any `Numeric` type. Btw note that if you don't set locale your decimal and grouping separator might change.

Answer (score 1):

/*
     This method is used to convert Price With Seprator
     */

```
 class func convertPriceWithSeprator(_ price: Double) -> String{
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.groupingSeparator = ","
        numberFormatter.groupingSize = 3
        numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
        numberFormatter.decimalSeparator = "."
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        return numberFormatter.string(from: price as NSNumber)!
    }
```

Comment: you need `numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2` as well

Comment: Thanks for your answer i got it fixed. @Ketan Sodvadiya

Comment: There is no need to initialize a new `NSNumber` object. you can use Formatter's method `string(for: Any)` and pass any `Numeric`
 type. Note that this will create a new number formatter instance every time you call this method

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can change your `numberFormatter.numberStyle` to `.currency`.